# Unpredictable Results Error in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I have been getting some errors with the indexes. I have run a query below to show what I did:

```
cqlsh> SELECT column_name, index_name, index_options, index_type,   component_index  FROM system.schema_columns  WHERE keyspace_name='casslink'AND columnfamily_name='mylink_all';

 column_name | index_name | index_options | index_type | component_index
 crawled |     mylink_all_crawledIndex | {} | COMPOSITES |   0
 detailpage |  mylink_all_detailIndex |   {} | COMPOSITES |  0
 linkurl |  null |   null |    null |   null
```

The design is that linkurl is a primary key, and crawled is a true/false field (0/1) and detailPage is a classifier for a type of page. The data is created and when I try running a query using AND I find an warning appears:

```
cqlsh> select linkurl from casslink.mylink_all 
   ... where crawled=1 
   ... and detailpage = 0 limit 10;

Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and
thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the 
performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

I think this is basically an error. I simply want to select records based on the crawled=1 and detailpage= 0. In a older style of SQL type of database that is fairly standard. But this seems to cause an issue in Cassandra.

Is there a better way to index and select in this example?

Comment: You talk about the design but it's much clearer to just display the table schema to us, use `DESCRIBE TABLE csslink.mylink_all` & post your schema to help us workout what's happening. Also what you are getting isn't an error, it's a warning telling you your schema / query need optimisation as in it's current state you'll have to parse the entire table and filter out sections to get what you want. You can do this by appending `ALLOW FILTERING` to your query but the warning tells you that doing so is unperformant. As for the better way of doing it, posting the table schema will help us decide.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a select on a column which is not a partition key. It is an indexed column, but from what I understand, it only has 2  potential values, which is not got for index or partition key. 
In this case, I would suggest adding another table which will contain only crawled links and select from it.

As far as what you are doing being standard in SQL type of databases, Cassandra is not one, and data modeling and query rules are very different, some of them are:

- Model for queries, not data
- It is ok to denormalize
- Indexes are not
  fast

There is a good primer on data modeling for Cassandra here: : https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_music_service_c.html

Answer (score 0):

What I did finally was join the two values into one field and hence there are now 4 values for one field. This seems to work.